# Typeorm using class-transformer to change value in table

Tags: typeorm, nest, class-transformer

I'm using Nest.js with Typeorm and library `class-transformer`:

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
@Transform(
    ({ value }) => `${value}/${moment().format('MM-YYYY')}`,
)
invoiceNumber: string;
```

I'm trying to generate somethink like this: `1/01-2022`. But still I have only an number e.g `1` (without date).

How I can add date to incremented value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`transformer`](https://typeorm.io/entities#column-options) option.

> *Specifies a value transformer (or array of value transformers) that is to be used to (un)marshal this column when reading or writing to the database. In case of an array, the value transformers will be applied in the natural order from entityValue to databaseValue, and in reverse order from databaseValue to entityValue.*
>
> Source: [TypeORM Documentation](https://typeorm.io/)

`transformer` has two methods:

1. `to`: Used to marshal data when writing to the database.
2. `from`: Used to unmarshal data when reading from the database.

```js
class YourClass {
  @Column({
    primary: true, // Marks column as primary
    transformer: {
      to(value) {
        // Transform 'invoiceNumber'
        return `${value}/${moment().format('MM-YYYY')}`;
      }
      from(value) {
        // Do nothing
        return value;
      }
    },
    /* Other options... */
  })
  invoiceNumber: string;
}
```

Note that the decorator is no more `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` but a "simple" `@Column` with `primary` option set to `true`.
The previous decorator is *only used as a table-generated primary column.
Column it creates is primary and its value is auto-generated.*

Comment: I don't know why, but `value` return `undefined` in `to`

Comment: When you save an entity you must populate the Invoice number with a value otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: If you want something automatically generated you must do this on the DB. E.g autoincrement